# eigenvalues of operators in projected subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working with a set of anti-commuting Hermitian matrices of same size X,Y,Z,W(which I am not sure, is important for the solution to this question or not). Here $A^2=1$ for $A={X,Y,Z,W}$. I work in a projected subspace where the eigenvalue of matrix XYZW is +1 i.e.$XYZW\equiv 1$. I want to know whether Y would also be restricted to subspace $YZW\equiv 1$ because $X^2\equiv 1$. This does not seem to hold but $XY\equiv WZ$ seem to hold i.e. in the projected space, action of $XY$ and $WZ$ will result in same eigenvalue when they act on their common set of eigenstates ($[XY,WZ]=0$). I am looking for a consistent approach to check when the eigenvalues of certain operators be same and restricted to some value in this projected subspace.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. To begin with there is no reason that one could restrict $Y$ (or $Z$) to the eigenspace of $X$ unless it is given that $Y$ (respectively $X$) commutes with $X$. Did you by any means forget to mention such a hypothesis?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : thanks for the comment. You are right. I changed my description to the exact problem I am dealing with. Hope it helps.